# Can worship only means prayers of five times?

Tags: ibadah

Does worship meaning complete by praying 5 times in a day or fasting in the month of Ramadan or by obeying the five pillars of Islam?Is there any thing else except prayers, fasting, zakat and hajj is included in worship?

If yes then what are these things from we spend our whole day in worship.

Answer (score 2):

**In the name of God, the Most Beneficent, the Merciful**

**All praise is due to God (ﷻ), the Lord of the Worlds. The Beneficent, the Merciful. Master of the Day of Judgement, and God’s Peace and Blessings be upon Muhammad (ﷺ), his family, his noble Companions, and all those who follow them.**

---

**Your question:** Can worship only means prayers of five times?

**Answer:** No, worship means performing x5 a day prayers, making Du’a to God only and asking things to have from Him only and plus there are many things that are considered an act of worship. Worship refers to our efforts of devotion towards the Divine, such as daily ritual prayer (salat), fasting in Ramadan (sawm), yearly almsgiving to the poor (zakat), and the pilgrimage to Mecca (hajj). It also includes one’s (optional) daily routine of litanies, such as reading the Qur’an, supplication, etc. as God Says:

> ”Righteousness is not that you turn your faces toward the east or the west, but [true] righteousness is [in] one who believes in God, the Last Day, the Angels, the Book, and the prophets and gives wealth, in spite of love for it, to relatives, orphans, the needy, the traveller, those who ask [for help], and for freeing slaves; [and who] establishes prayer and gives Zakah; [those who] fulfil their promise when they promise; and [those who] are patient in poverty and hardship and during battle. Those are the ones who have been true, and it is those who are the righteous.” **[Quran: 2:177]**

In Islam, the performing of one's duties is also considered an act of worship. The Prophet ￼ told us that whatever one spends on his family will be counted as an act of worship for which he will be rewarded, provided what he spent was acquired by Islamically acceptable means. Kindness to family members, no matter how small, is also viewed as an act of worship. Even activities that we enjoy very much, such as sexual relations with one's spouse, are considered acts of worship as long as they are performed in accordance with the relevant Quranic and prophetic guidelines. For example, the Prophet ￼ once told his Companions that they would be rewarded even for engaging in sexual intercourse with their wives. They were astonished and asked: “Are we to be rewarded for doing something that we enjoy very much?"

The Prophet ￼ replied: “If you satisfy your desires illegally, will you be punished?"

They replied: "Yes."

the Prophet ￼ said: "So for satisfying it legally with your wives, you will be rewarded."

---

**Sources:**

**1.** [**seekershib.org**](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2013/02/08/the-meaning-of-worship-and-submission-in-islam/)

**2.** [**islamweb.net**](http://www.islamweb.net/en/article/76851/worship-in-islam)

Answer (score 0):

I believe Alex explained a lot. I'll add to that the answer to your question is very broad.

First of all, during prayer for example, some people feel more humbleness and submission than others. It has to do with Iman and how close to Allah you feel and how pure you feel your heart is; so that's one thing you can work on. As for rituals of ibadah, that's it. You can make more prayers besides the main 5, like the Sunnah prayers; you can fast more if you want, besides the month of Ramadan. You can give more money to poor besides Zakah.

Second, What you just mentioned are rituals of ibadah, but ibadah in Islam is not only rituals.

- Being nice to your neighbor is ibadah
- taking care of your relatives is ibadah
- Working 8 hours a day to provide to your family is ibadah
- Jihad  (struggle), in a sense of struggling to lift oppression off of people (helping the poor, standing up for your innocent colleague at work who's being accused of something, even working to be a leader in your society is a form of jihad) is ibadah
- Removing harm from the street/road (removing a rock, covering an open manhole/sewer hole etc...) is ibadah

There are plenty forms of ibadah. Too many to cover in a short answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assalamu alaykum,
There are many ways of worship, such as: five daily prayers, dua, repentance, forgiveness, generosity, kindness, helpful, loyalty, honesty, doping more good deeds, doing less good deeds, etc. These are afew examples of worship. However, there are many more that this. I hope I have helped you in what you need. Jazzak Allah

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model i.e. what is on- and what is off-topic here I suggest you to take the [Tour] and check our [help].